# Using History object/javascript to redirect the user to a specific anchor when they press the back button?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

I'm currently having an issue where the user is browsing a page with a long list of items with brief detail all laid out in a table. If the user wants to see more information about the item, they can click the link to view specific details on a separate page. Each  tag has a unique id attribute. The problem I'm having is that when the list is very long (perhaps > 100 items) if the user wants to take a look at an item and then wants to click the back button, it takes them to the top of the previous page, losing their spot in the list.

I know there are a handful of solutions from the user's end like middle-click/open in new tab, from a website design standpoint (allow a smaller number of results in the table so they don't run into the problem of being so hard to find the spot they were at when they click the back button), etc.

I tried looking into using the History object and javascript, and thought I had seen somewhere that I could replace the LAST history entry, but all I can find are how to replace the CURRENT history entry. Ultimately what I'm looking to do is replace where the back button would normally take me to with that same url with the anchor of the  element appended to the end.

i.e. If the user is on www.website.com/listAllItems and clicks the link for an item to go to www.website.com/viewItem?itemId=1234, I would like to change the last history entry to be www.website.com/listAllItems#1234 or similar.

Am I misunderstanding how the History object works? I'm hoping to be able to accomplish this without the use of a library. It seems like I've been VERY close to a solution several times, but it's always just a tiny bit off. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you go back the browser restores the scroll position. Is that not happening for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

I just use a cookie. I save the id of the last clicked item in the cookie, and then on load I get the id from the cookie, use that to query the dom for the element, and then set focus to it. i also used JQuery in my personal project, so i converted into straight JS for this answer since the question is tagged as javascript, i hope my conversion is alright.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = $.trim(ca[i]);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

element.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
   setCookie(document.URL + '-lastclick', element.getAttribute('id'))
});

window.onload = function() {
  var elementId = getCookie(document.URL + '-lastclick');
  document.getElementById(elementId).focus();

  // personally i do a .animate({ scrollTop: pos}) to scroll to my object, but you get the gyst.
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work very will if you happen to have two instance of this going on at the same time. One will override the other.

Comment: it should only save one instance per url, i dont think ive ever run into issues with multiple instances, that i know of.

Comment: A user can load up multiple tabs of your site.

Comment: but cookies are shared between tabs, so if they open up a new tab, they are taken straight to where they were last, not such a bad thing.

Comment: granted... you're smarter than me, so you may be barking up the right tree, and I may be oblivious to the shortcomings of my solution. :)